# How to compare and store data elements of 2 vectors position wise?

Tags: c++, vector

How to compare data elements of 2 vectors(index by index) and store the difference elemnts in the 3rd vector.This `set_difference` is provide almost every thing but i want to compare data elements `location wise` location wise not just by sorting them.

i.e `std::vector<double> m_vector1` has elements (3,7,8,9) 4 elements on the location 0,1,2,3 respectively.

`std::vector<double> m_vector2` has elements (3,5,7,9) 4 elements on the location 0,1,2,3  respectively.

`std::vector<double> m_vector3 (5,7)`When i compare data this vector  should store the changed data of `vector 2` on the locations  `[0](5) and [1](7)`.

**Please Note:** If i use `set_difference` it will give me only 5 and i want 5 and 7 because data values has changed on both locations.

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to build something out of `std::mismatch`.

Comment: @chris: Yes i need std:: mismatch but how to store those mismatch elements in a third vector. Can you please write ?

Comment: Do note that you may or may not have to do something extra since the vectors contain floating-point numbers, which don't work well with equality in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that leverages [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) to find the mismatching pairs for you. You pass the same arguments as you would to `std::mismatch` and it gives back a vector of the appropriate type. Some of the drawn out stuff (like figuring out the type) can be severely reduced with C++11 and C++14, but the function as is works with C++03.

```
template<typename It>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> 
all_mismatches(It first, It last, It first2) {
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> ret;

    for (std::pair<It, It> p = std::make_pair(first, first2);
        (p = std::mismatch(p.first, last, p.second)).first != last;
        ++p.first, ++p.second
    ) { 
        ret.push_back(*p.second);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

A special note since you're comparing `double`s is that if you're unsure that they will compare exactly equal, you can just take an extra `Compare` type argument and function argument to handle the floating-point comparison and pass it straight to `std::mismatch`.

Finally, this assumes the first range is the shorter range, just like `std::mismatch` until C++14. If you want, you can do what `std::mismatch` does now and take two full ranges and then make sure you don't go beyond the end of either, or just pass both into `std::mismatch` and let it do the work if you have C++14 available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard algorithm `std::copy_if` with a lambda expression or write the corresponding loop yourself.

For example

```
#includde <algorithm>
#include <oterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
P
//...other stuff
   std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = m_vector1.begin();

   std::copy_if( m_vector2.begin(), m_vector2.end(), std::back_inserter( m_vector3 ),
                 [&]( double x ) { return ( x != *it1++ ); } );
```

Or

```
   std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = m_vector1.begin();
   for ( double x : m_vector2 )
   {
       if ( x != *it1++ ) m_vector3.push_back( x );
   }
```